# How can I change the `Blob path begins with` in the Azure data factory storage event trigger using azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I have set a storage event trigger for the pipelines in the azure data factory Dev environment. the `blob path begins with` is different in the dev environment and other environments (Staging and Production). I thought about parametrizing it, but it seems it is not possible to use dynamic content there. Does anyone know of a way to change it in the azure DevOps pipeline or in any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not possible to parametrize `blob path begins with` in the Azure data factory storage event trigger, I decided to modify the `ARMTemplateForFactory.json` in the `adf_publish` branch directly from the Azure DevOps pipeline using a PowerShell script. I am going to share my script here:

````
param(
[String] $ADFArmPath
)

$JsonData = (Get-Content $ADFArmPath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)


$JsonData.update | % { if($JsonData.resources.properties)
    {
        foreach ($ItemName in $JsonData.resources.properties ) {
                if($ItemName.type -eq "BlobEventsTrigger")
                {
                $ItemName.typeProperties.blobPathBeginsWith = $ItemName.typeProperties.blobPathBeginsWith.replace('x','y')                       
                    }
                }
            }
    }
    
   $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100  | set-content $ADFArmPath ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to parameterize `blob path begins with` field in Storage event triggers at this moment. You need to create multiple triggers to achieve the requirement.